# Completeness problem of TM

Tags: computability, turing-machines, semi-decidability

$L = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid L(M) = \Sigma^∗ \}$

Is above problem R.E ?

I found an explanation in one of the websites and I have doubt in few lines of paragraph.

The explanation was

Now, given a halting problem $(\langle H \rangle, w)$, we proceed as follows: We make a new TM say $A$, which on input $x$, just simulates $H$ on $w$ for $|x|$ steps. If $H$ halts on $w$, $A$ goes to reject state. Otherwise it accepts. So, $L(A)=\Sigma^*$ if $H$ does not halt on $w$ and $L(A) =$ a finite set if $H$ halts on $w$. So we can reduce non halting problem to this problem. Hence given language is non R.E

Can someone please explain me how is $L(A) = \Sigma^∗$ if $H$ does not halt on $w$ ? It says if $A$ doesn't halt within $|x|$ steps then $L(A)$ is infinite. How can we say that ? What it TM $A$ halts on $|x+1|$ th  step? Even then it will be finite but this explanation considers it as infinite.

I understand how is it finite set if $H$ halts on w but I am not able to understand the non halting part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $H$ does not halt on $w$. To prove $L(A) = \Sigma^∗$ we need to show that $A$ accepts every $x$. Indeed, whatever $x$ is, we simulate the execution of $H$ on $w$ for only $|x|$ steps (a finite, known amount of steps). I.e., we do not simply run that program on its own, we keep an "alarm clock" counting the steps $H$ as it is running, and as soon as it reaches $|x|$ the alarm rings and we stop the simulation. In this way, no matter what $H$ does on $w$, the simulation will always terminate: either because $H$ halts before $|x|$ steps, or because the alarm rings and we abort the simulation.

Now, since $H$ does not halt on $w$ by hypothesis, $H$ will always make the alarm ring. In such case, $A$ accepts $x$ by construction, hence $A$ indeed accepts all inputs $x$.

For the other direction, assume that instead $H$ does halt on $w$. Let's write $k$ for the number of steps that make $H$ halt on $w$. We now need to prove that $L(A) \neq \Sigma^∗$. Take $x = 1^k$: we prove that $A$ rejects it. By definition, $A$ simulates $H$ on $w$ for $|x|=k$ steps, and that's just enough time to make $H$ halt. So, by construction $A$ rejects.

Comment: How can you say that " H does not halt on w" by just simulating for x steps ? If we run the TM for **x steps**, we can only say that H doesn't halt on **w** within **x steps** right ? H **may halt** on w after x steps.

Comment: @RajeshR That's correct: we can't decide whether H halts on w. We can decide another property, namely if x steps are enough for H to halt on w. If x is enough, we are sure H does halt on w. But, as you say, if it is not enough, we can not conclude that H diverges on w (nor that it halts). I can't see the relation to the answer above, though (?)

Comment: According to me, non halting problem says whether M **does not** halt on w or not (yes case being M does not halt on w) **and not**  whether M does not halt on w **within x steps** . So how are you solving non halting problem(which is part of your proof) by simulating M for just x steps?

Comment: @RajeshR I am not solving the halting problem running only x steps -- that's impossible. Can you point me to the line(s) in the answer above which makes you think so?

Comment: I think that you are trying to prove by contradiction that " if there exists a **recognizer** for completeness problem, then **non halting** problem could be solved. But as **non halting** problem is known to be non R.E, completness problem is also non R.E" . This is what I could infer from your second paragraph. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @RajeshR The reasoning above does not deal with RE, yet. Above, I prove that $H$ does not halt on $w$ if and only if $L(A)=\Sigma^*$, where $A$ is the TM constructed by the OP from $H,w$. What can be computed here is $A$ from $H,w$: this is needed for having a reduction. This provides the computable total function for the needed m-reduction, from the non-halting problem to OP's $L$. Given this m-reduction, we have that $L$ can not be RE since otherwise the non-halting problem (which m-reduces to $L$) would also be RE -- but we know this is not the case.

Comment: @RajeshR In other words, above I do not show the non-RE part: the OP already did that. Above, I only show that the $A$ the OP defined indeed provides a m-reduction (i.e. the mentioned "if and only if" holds).

Comment: "Above, I prove that H does not halt on w if and only if L(A)=Σ* " . This is what I am saying, how can you say that H does not halt on w by just simulating it on w for x steps?

Comment: Suppose H halts on w in $k+2$ steps and $|x| = k$. According to your reduction, you say that H does not halt on w and accepts x. But H indeed halts on w but after k steps.

Comment: @RajeshR I don't say that. I say that L(A) is not the full language since A rejects any x st |x|=k+2. So, we discover that H halts on w only when A is fed a large enough x, which is feasible to check.