# Difficulty in reducing non halting problem to a given problem

Tags: turing-machines, computability

I am having difficulty in reducing non halting problem to the given problem to prove that language is non R.E

For eg [Completeness problem of TM](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83842/completeness-problem-of-tm) .

In the above problem, we accept $\Sigma^*$ if H does not halt on w . For doing that, we give an input $x$ and simulate H on w for $|x|$ steps. I don't understand how can we deduce that H does not halt on w by just simulating H on w for $|x|$ steps.

Suppose H halts on w after $k+2$ steps and $|x| = k$. Now if we simulate H on w only for $k$ steps, how can we say that H will never halt or does not halt on w? It does not halt after $k$ steps but halts after $k+2$ steps.

I think that non halting problem is whether H does not halt on w **and not** whether H does not halt on w in **k steps**.

Can someone please help me in understanding the reduction?

Comment: Reducing $A$ to $B$ does not involve deciding $A$, nor deciding $B$. In the linked question, non-halting is reduced to a language $L$, without deciding non-halting, and without deciding $L$. The reduction exploits that "halts in k steps" is decidable, but that's not used to decide non-halting, or deciding $L$. It is exploited only to make it an m-reduction.

Comment: @RajeshR I was busy, so couldn't reply. What language do you want to reduce to what language? Please define them (both!) in your post *using set theoretic notation*. In particular, what do you mean by "non-halting language"? Is it complement of the language of the Halting problem? The language of the Halting problem is defined as $A_{TM} = \{\langle M,w \rangle \mid M \text{ halts on } w\}$.

Comment: @fade2black, In my question I have said "non halting problem". I want to reduce non halting problem to completeness problem of TM. Non halting problem is, given Turing machine H and input w, we have to decide whether H does not halt on w.